# How to handle not clickable condition

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, conditional-statements, wait

I am using implicitly wait in my script, the problem is in one scenario the element is found but it is not in clickable state, in this case I am not able to use explicitly wait. How can I handle this scenario pls help me.

Comment: ImplicitWait allows you just to wait for element to appear in DOM. In case you need to wait until element becomes clickable you need ExplicitWait. What is the reason for *"... I am not able to use explicitly wait"*?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Ya the problem is am getting is  webdriver exception description is element is not clickable at point. Other element would receive the click

Answer (score 2):

You can use both Implicit Wait & Explicit Wait  in your script, 
If you want webDriver to wait until element is clickable use Explicit wait before perform click(); action on that element.

[image]

```
String elementid = ""; //put id of element inside " --- ";
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id(elementid));
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(element));
element.click();
```